# Rollback a deployment/publishing?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, web-deployment, rollback, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to rollback a Windows Azure Website and SQL deployment / publishing?

I published a website, now it's causing a lot of errors, and I want to get back to the previous state and work on the code some more.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Git or TFS you can take advantage of deployment rollback by selecting the previous deployment (as explained by [Nathan Totten](https://ntotten.com/2012/06/07/10-things-about-windows-azure-web-sites/)):

[image]

To rollback the database you can do several things. The easiest could be to use EF Migrations:

- Run EF Migrations from your Application_Start (not sure if this is something you want to do
- (Manually) call [migrations.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307):

  Migrate.exe MyApp.exe /startupConfigurationFile=”MyApp.exe.config” /targetMigration=”MyPreviousVersion”

Comment: I am unable to find this blade in azure..can you Please help me to locate the same? I tried all the options.